# Flutter/Dart runtime type of freezed object

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to switch runtime typed of my @freezed objects. Simple naming is not working f.e

```
case Person:
```

but debugger is saying it is something like:

```
_$_Person
```

which is private i guess so i can't properly switch this runtimeType.

Any thoughts? I don't really want to make this type public, as it is generated this way.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do requires Pattern Matching, which dart doesn't have.

Generally switch/cases are only good for constants & known values. in your use case, you should use if/else:

```dart
void doStuff(obj){
    if(obj is Person){
      // true if _$_Person extends Person
    } else {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue until I realized I was doing type checking all wrong.
I was using the `==` operator, like this:

```
(data.runtimeType == Chapter)
```

however this is not how you are supposed to check types.
We should be using the `is` syntax.

```
(data is Chapter)
```

It's that simple!

Answer (score 0):

For Dart 3, `freezed` recommends using [Patterns](https://dart.dev/language/patterns) for this:

```dart
switch (myObject) {
    Person() => // can use myObject as an instance of Person 
    _ => 'Unknown type ${myObject.runtimeType}',
};
```

With this approach there's no need to make any private classes public.